# MSMQ on Azure Website

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have an existing ASP.NET Web Service (asmx), which I am trying to move into Azure. The logging component of the web service logs the messages in to MSMQ and there is a windows service which reads the message and update the database.

Is this possible using Azure Web APP (Websites) ? Will the web service code be able to create message queues at run time and could push messages into it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSMQ isn't available as an Azure service and you can't create a Windows service with App Service.  What you can do is use a storage queue instead of MSMQ with minimal impact on your Web service code.  Replace you Windows service with a Web Job that will be triggered when a new message is sent to the queue.  You'll have to do a little refactoring but it shouldn't be that bad.

Here's a link to get you started: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/