# Is it possible to send messages to msmq from azure web app

Tags: azure, msmq

I would like to setup an azure web service and an azure vm that is running msmq. Can I send messages to the vm's msmq? I noticed in the documentation for msmq on azure, that sending messages with http to msmq on azure is not supported, but I thought there might be some other means of sending messages to msmq from an azure web app.
Has anyone actually set this up? If this is not possible do we need to use service bus instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Azure Storage Queue or Azure Service Bus Queue instead of MSMQ. But still if you want to use MSMQ on Azure Virtual Machine, you have the official documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn529082.aspx).

Also, the difference between storage queue and service bus queue is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted), so you can check out which one suits you the best.

Comment: Can I ask what is the basis for your suggestion?

Comment: Sure. Here's the link to the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399176/msmq-on-azure-website?rq=1